# Are there other prepositions beyond "from" and "by" that are used with "inspire"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Are there any other prepositions to use with the verb *inspire* other than "from" and  "by"?

Example:

> He also inspired me ______ how important the teachers are to their students.

Comment: I don't know that I understand your question. Neither from nor by would work in your example sentence.

Comment: The preposition **with** would work in your example sentence: "He also inspired me with how important the teachers are to their students." (Note that "students" should be plural.) Even so, the use of "inspired me" is questionable in this sentence. Do you mean to say, "He also **impressed on me** how important the teachers are to their students"? One is usually not inspired by importance. This might be better said in two sentences: 1.) He inspired me to/by/with [whatever]. 2.) He made me realize how important the teachers are to their students.

Comment: Thank you Mark and Catija. 
Yes, of course. Students should be plural.
I was writing this sentence in a cover letter. I think inspiration brings ideas to your mind. He brought this idea to my mind as he was a source of inspiration. That's how I thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other prepositions that can be used with the verb "inspire" but each means a slightly different thing, and none work with the second half of this sentence.

> He *inspired me **by*** [doing something inspirational].
>
> He *inspired me **with*** [his inspirational behavior/messages].
>
> He *inspired me **through*** [his inspirational messages/behavior].
>
> He *inspired me **to*** [also do that inspirational thing].

Outside of a more elaborate sentence structure, these four prepositions are going to be your typical options. None of these quite fits for "...how important teachers are to their students."

You can keep the structure the same by using a different verb. There are plenty of different words that fit grammatically, but each has a slightly different implication about the way he gave this information to you. Here are a few options:

> He *showed* me how important the teachers are to their students.
>
> He *taught* me how important the teachers are to their students.
>
> He *demonstrated to* me how important the teachers are to their students.

If you prefer to keep the verb "inspire" then we can instead add a few more words.

> He inspired me *with his belief of* how important the teachers are to their students.

Answer (score 0):

"Inspired from" is not correct. One can take inspiration from something, but then the verb is "take" and *inspiration* is a noun.

There are other prepositions that could follow *inspire* as a verb. For example, one can inspire people **through** great leadership.